# Adding share button on fancybox 3

Tags: jquery, fancybox, tumblr, fancybox-3

Share buttons are not present by default, and I'm wondering how to add it. Is there any other method than this?

```
$('[data-fancybox="XXXXX"]').fancybox({
    buttons : [
        'share',
        'fullScreen',
        'close'
    ]
})
```

I'm on Tumblr, and using a Tumblr tag for data-fancybox (i.e. data-fancybox="{PostID}"), but using {PostID} for XXXXX in the code above doesn't work.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, there are two methods:

1) Use `$( selector ).fancybox( options );` to select your links and to apply your custom options.

Demo - https://codepen.io/fancyapps/pen/vzoPMB?editors=1010

Note: You can use any selector, it is not necessary to use `'[data-fancybox="XXXXX"]'`, you could use, for example, `'.imglist a'`, demo - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YJaOVo?editors=1010

2) Simply change defaults, for example:

```
$.fancybox.defaults.buttons = [ 
  'slideShow',
  'share',
  'zoom',
  'fullScreen',
  'close'
];
```

Comment: Thanks @Janis, you made my day! I went with the second option, and worked perfectly!